# SSH unzip AND change the filename (or get the filename contained therein)

Tags: ssh, unzip

```
/usr/bin/curl http://somewebsite.com/foo.zip -o 4232.zip
unzip -o -q -L 4232.zip
chown 508 /home/me/www/inbound/data/??????.xml
rm -f 4232.zip
```

I am using this SSH script to download a zip file called foo.zip, rename the file to 4232.zip, the extract the contents.

My problem is that the zip file contains a single file whose name is constantly changing.  I cannot see a flag for unzip that lets me rename the file(s) inside the zip.

How can I rename the mystery file inside.  There is really only ever one file in my immediate project.
-or-
How can I get that filename so I can change ownership and use it in a PHP script that will process it later on...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will tell you the name of the .xml file in the zip

```
unzip -l z.zip | grep -o  '[^/]*\.xml'
```

If you want to extract and rename the xml file

```
unzip -p z.zip \*.xml | cat > NEWFILE.xml
```

Comment: That would work except that there are other files in the folder... I suppose I could expand it into its own folder, but ideally I would like to know the filename(s) inside the zip that I am expanding...

Comment: Other .xml files or just other files?

Comment: xml files... it is a directory where I dump inbound data... but one source zips theirs and the contents of the zip file are always dynamic names... (I know, I could ask them to make it a static name, but I really want to know how to solve this one)

Comment: Sweet.  I did not now about using the cat to simply pipe the data to a new file name.  Thanks.

Comment: any way of doing this with a directory instead of a file?